# VB.net lauching a program from sub folder

Tags: vb.net, process.start, external-application

So I need to lauch an external application from the sub folder of the program. The application will be deployed with the program but may be in different locations so I can't hardcode it to "c:\folder\example.exe"

When I run this I get an error that file cannot be found although I have the folder and file in \bin\debug.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\app\ds104.exe")
End Sub
```

Even when the application is in the root folder which will not be ideal I get the same error.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ds104.exe")
End Sub
```

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: You need to remove the first backslash. Anyway can you check what is the value of "Environment.CurrentDirectory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Process.Start()` method takes a full path as the argument.

You can get the path your application is running from by using the `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` property. You then join it with the location of the application you want to run and then call the `Process.Start()` method.

Example:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

...

Private Sub StartApplication()
    Process.Start(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Path\To\App.exe")
End Sub
```

Comment: I was being an idiot and didn't realize the version (which is its name) of the app was different. But I like the "My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath &" and will look into it.